# DataWriter.WriteUInt32 equivalent in .NET Socket?

Tags: .net, sockets, uwp

We have a UWP app that has a Listener which uses **DataReader.ReadUInt32()** where we specify the length of the message we pass. Before, it was only listening from other UWP apps which uses **DataWriter.WriteUInt32()** so it was properly able to read it.

Now we are adding .NET apps that communicate with the UWP apps. The problem is, Socket in .NET doesn't seem to have an equivalent of the WriteUInt32() method. So what happens is, ReadUInt32() seems to output incorrect data (ex. 825373492).

Below is a code snippet of our Sender and Listener:

Sender:

```
            using (var socket = new StreamSocket())
            {
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cts.CancelAfter(5000);
                await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, peerSplit[1]).AsTask(cts.Token);

                var writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
                if (includeSize) writer.WriteUInt32(writer.MeasureString(message));
                writer.WriteString(message);
                await writer.StoreAsync();
                writer.DetachStream();
                writer.Dispose();
            }
```

Listener:

```
                // Read first 4 bytes (length of the subsequent string).
                var sizeFieldCount = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
                if (sizeFieldCount != sizeof(uint))
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                    reader.DetachStream();
                    return;
                }
                // Read the string.
                var stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
                var actualStringLength = await reader.LoadAsync(stringLength);
                if (stringLength != actualStringLength)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data.
                    return;
                }

                var message = reader.ReadString(actualStringLength);
```

Is there an equivalent of WriteUInt32() in .NET Socket?

Answer (score 2):

[DataWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.aspx) class is not supported in a .NET project like console. We can use [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) class which has same features and methods like `DataWriter` in uwp app.  For [`DataWriter.WriteUInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.writeuint32) method, `BinaryWriter` has [`Write(UInt32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d79ecdwh(v=vs.110).aspx) method. But if you use `BinaryWriter` in one side of socket, you will need to use [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class for reading on the other side, `DataReader` may not read the right data. For example, if  `Write(UInt32)` on the server side, we need to [`BinaryReader.ReadUInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readuint32(v=vs.110).aspx) on the client side. `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` are supported in uwp app. So the example code as follows:

Writer on server side(.Net console project)

```
  Socket socket = myList.AcceptSocket();
  NetworkStream output = new NetworkStream(socket);
  using (BinaryWriter binarywriter = new BinaryWriter(output))
  {
      UInt32 testuint = 28;
      binarywriter.Write(testuint);
      binarywriter.Write("Server Say Hello");
  }
```

Reader on client sode(uwp app)

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
{                
    try
    {       
        var stringLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
        var stringtext= reader.ReadString();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return (e.ToString());
    }
}
```